# My hamburguer menu works on every device except on iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I have made a menu using HTML and CSS. It uses links. It works on any device, but at 768px, the menu stops working and I can’t find the reason.

Can anyone help me?

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <h2 style="display:none;">Navegación KSLM</h2>
  <a class="klsm" href="#">KSLM</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" id="#tog" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>        
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#inicio">INICIO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#acercade">ACERCA DE</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#servicios">SERVICIOS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#ubicacion">UBICACIÓN</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contacto">CONTACTO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/kslmconsultores/?notify_field=blurb&modal=profile_completion&notif_id=1530027180752658&notif_t=page_profile_blurb "></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "navbar-expand-md". However you want to show hamrburger menu in Ipad portrait(768), so expand your menu in lg screens (992px). Use class "navbar-expand-lg" instead

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <h2 style="display:none;">Navegación KSLM</h2>
  <a class="klsm" href="#">KSLM</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" id="#tog" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>        
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#inicio">INICIO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#acercade">ACERCA DE</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#servicios">SERVICIOS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#ubicacion">UBICACIÓN</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contacto">CONTACTO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/kslmconsultores/?notify_field=blurb&modal=profile_completion&notif_id=1530027180752658&notif_t=page_profile_blurb "></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```